# Conditional Where Clause in SQL Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I have developing the MVC application for generating the report. I have provided many search option like below

```
Customer id
Customer name
Customer E-mail
State
Country
```

User 1:

If the some user will give inputs to only some Values like

```
Customer id = 1
Customer name = A
```

By default other parameters are passed as null to the stored procedure.

```
Customer E-mail
State
Country
```

User 2:

If the some user will give inputs to only some values like

Customer E-mail=xtz@gmail.com

By default other parameters are passed as null to the stored procedure.

```
Customer id
Customer name
State
Country
```

How can i use the where clause in the SQL query in the stored procedure. Can we do it like below

```
string qry = select * from table_name where status != d

if (@customerID!=null)
    qry = qry + "and customer_id=@customerID"
if (@customerName!=null)
    qry = qry + "and customer_name=@customerName"
```

Please let me the best approach on this.

Thanks,
Velu

Answer (score 14):

If you are creating dynamic SQL then you can do just like you are above:

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @SQL =  'SELECT * FROM TABLE '
if (@customerID IS NOT NULL)
    SQL = SQL + " AND customer_id = @customerID"
```

Or another option is to handle it like

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE
WHERE (@customerID IS NULL OR customer_id = @customerID)
```

I prefer the second as it is utilizing parametrized variable. First example needs to take into consideration malicious input far more intensely.

Comment: `I prefer the second as it is utilizing parametrized variable`  not optimized, see http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DBProgramming/do-you-use-column-param-or-param-is-null  you can use `sp_executesql` to build a safe string

Comment: I agree, but I have also not had trouble with it on fairly large volume applications. So the balance between security/performance has to be weighed. All in all I do agree it is not the best execution plan.

Comment: not to nitpick but this `if (@customerID != null)` won't catch nulls, you need `if (@customerID IS NOT null)`

Answer (score 5):

You could do dynamic SQL, but a simpler method is:

```
WHERE (ISNULL(@param1,1) = 1 OR [col1] = @param1)
    AND (ISNULL(@param2,1) = 1 OR [col2] = @param2)
    AND ...
```

Comment: And you just flushed your indexes down the toilet with that non `SARGable` query

Comment: @SQLMenace, @Remus: interesting how you divine a performance problem with a db schema and software you've not seen, and have not run a query against.  Anyone knows that this is best handled peformance-wise by a purpose-designed stored procedure, but I felt that was a bit beyond the context of the question.  The OP was comparing to null, which sets the level of the discussion, don't you think?

Answer (score 0):

you'll have to pass all the variables as parameters into the SP and then do your logic in there.

```
SqlCommand cmd  = new SqlCommand("STORED_PROC_NAME", conn);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@CustomerID", custId));
var rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```